# What is the clear plastic sticker on New England Coffee bags for?

Tags: flavor, packaging

I got a couple bags of New England Coffee and noticed there is a clear plastic sticker with 9 holes in it on the front of each bag.  It seems like there are also small holes in the bag underneath that correspond to the holes in the sticker, but they are very small.  Also the sticker is very sticky (i.e. it is not meant to be removed).

Does anyone know what purpose this serves?  Is it for freshness somehow?

The sticker is always in the same place, and can be seen here if you zoom in and look closely.  It's Under the words "Chocolate Cappuccino", and its center is in the sky underneath.

[image: New England Coffee bag with square, clear plastic sticker]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good observation in both meanings. Yes, the transparent thing is for freshness. It is a one-way valve for the coffee to release redundant CO<sub>2</sub> gas out of the package.

A more common form can be seen [here](https://www.clearbags.com/bags/gusset/coffee).

If you want to learn about how CO<sub>2</sub> is emitted, you can search for [degassing](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/search?q=degassing).

Comment: This answer is exactly what i wanted to know, concise and descriptive with further reading.  And it arrived very quickly. I would have marked it correct sooner but i couldn't login for a bit... had a clash with stackoverflow account.  Anyway, thanks!!